Determine how many blocks are there in Rational Canonical Form
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$, let $T: V \to V$ be a  linear map, and suppose the minimal polynomial $m_T(x) = f(x)^k$, where $f(x) \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ is irreducible. The RCF theorem states that there exist a basis $B$ such that
$$[T]_B = C(f(x)^{k_1}) \oplus C(f(x)^{k_2}) \oplus \cdots \oplus C(f(x)^{k_r}), (k = k_1 \geq k_2 \geq \cdots \geq k_r),\text{uniquely determined by }T$$
$[T]_B$: the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$. $C(f(x))$: the companion matrix of $f(x)$.
It was mentioned in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEuf8E_OSB4 (3:05) that
$$r = \text{# of blocks} = \frac{\dim \ker(f(A)) }{\deg f(x)}, \text{ where } A = [T]_B $$
I have no direction as to how I can show this. A similar question is proposed in Number of blocks in rational canonical form but wasn't answered (Hoffman and Kunze did not provide a proof and claimed it's obvious).
Thanks in advance!

Hints: I think that it helps to work through through the most trivial case, where $f(x)=x$. In each Jordan block there's a contribution of $+1$ to the dimension of the kernel. For the general case you then need to see that in each of the factors $\mathbb{F}[x]/\langle f(x)^k\rangle$ there is a contribution of $\deg f$ to the kernel.

I'm taking linear algebra and is unfamilar with the module version of RCF. But I managed to show what you said. I typed up a proof below the post. Can you check its validity? Are there shorter ways of proving this?

I think what you've written in your solution is correct, although the notation is (to me) a bit confusing.

Thank you. @ancientmathematician

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and $T: V \to V$ a linear map with minimal polynomial $m_T(x) = f(x)^k$. Where $k$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}$. Suppose the cyclic decomposition of $V$ is
$$V = Z_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus Z_{n_1} \oplus Z_{n_1+1} \oplus \cdots \oplus Z_{n_1 + n_2} \oplus \cdots \oplus Z_{n_k}$$
Where $Z_i$s 're cyclic subspaces such that the $T$-annhilator of $Z_1$ to $Z_{n_1}$ is $f(x)^k$, $Z_{n_1+1}$ to $Z_{n_2}$ is $f(x)^{k-1}$, and so on.
Note that:
$$f(T)(V) = \bigoplus_{i=1}^{n_k} f(T)(Z_i)\implies \dim f(T)(V) = \sum_{i=1}^{n_k} \dim f(T)(Z_i)$$
For a cyclic subspace $Z$ with $T$-annhilator $f(x)^l$, $f(T)(Z)$ is a cyclic subspace with $T$-annhilator $f(x)^{l-1}$. Hence $\dim f(T)(Z) = d(l-1)$， where $d = \deg f$. Thus
$$\dim f(T)(V) = d \sum_{i=1}^{k}n_k (k-1) $$
By rank-nullity theorem:
$$
\dim \ker f(T) = \dim V - \dim f(T)(V) 
= d \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i l - d \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i (l-1) 
= d \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i$$
Finally
$$\text{Number of blocks} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} n_i  = \frac{\dim \ker f(T)}{\deg f(x)}$$
